# Npm install fails on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install

I installed `NodeJS` and `npm` by `apt-get`. Both of them gets installed perfectly.

When I run `node -v` I get the following

> v0.10.25

When I run `npm -v` I get the following

> 1.3.10

Now when I get to my projects root directory and try to run

```
sudo npm install
```

I get the following output with errors:

```
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/material-ui/0.14.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/radium/0.16.6
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-addons-css-transition-group/0.14.7
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react/0.14.7
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-addons-pure-render-mixin/0.14.7
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-addons-update/0.14.7
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-dom/0.14.6
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-lazyload/1.3.2
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-progress-bar-plus/0.2.3
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-router/2.0.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-scroll/1.0.3
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-tap-event-plugin/0.2.2
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-core/6.5.1
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-loader/6.2.2
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-preset-es2015/6.5.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-preset-react/6.5.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/babelify/7.2.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/css-loader/0.18.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/require-dir/0.1.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/style-loader/0.13.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/transfer-webpack-plugin/0.1.4
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/1.8.3
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/webpack/1.12.13
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/radium/0.16.6
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-addons-css-transition-group/0.14.7
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-addons-css-transition-group/-/react-addons-css-transition-group-0.14.7.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/radium/-/radium-0.16.6.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react/0.14.7
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react/-/react-0.14.7.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-addons-update/0.14.7
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-addons-update/-/react-addons-update-0.14.7.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-addons-pure-render-mixin/0.14.7
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-addons-pure-render-mixin/-/react-addons-pure-render-mixin-0.14.7.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-dom/0.14.6
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-dom/-/react-dom-0.14.6.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-progress-bar-plus/0.2.3
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-progress-bar-plus/-/react-progress-bar-plus-0.2.3.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/material-ui/0.14.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/material-ui/-/material-ui-0.14.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-scroll/1.0.3
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-scroll/-/react-scroll-1.0.3.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-router/2.0.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-router/-/react-router-2.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-tap-event-plugin/0.2.2
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-lazyload/1.3.2
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-core/6.5.1
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-tap-event-plugin/-/react-tap-event-plugin-0.2.2.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react-lazyload/-/react-lazyload-1.3.2.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-core/-/babel-core-6.5.1.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-loader/6.2.2
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-loader/-/babel-loader-6.2.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-preset-react/6.5.0
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
npm ERR! �Tێ�0����������o�jU�����

                                      `�/�M7�j��Y�Jڪ!0�3sf�x��� e)4D������.�    �r%�8�k�%���`}�A�4+�����}���nڒKK�ZW)���\� e�q&g�{�O�
6����֐��U����ض��p�z�����Ag����V̶�r�M��s��"��X��sފ���'Lrnu�:r��`.�$��f�s���m����                                                          �
                                          an�4_m��"
npm ERR! �$�l�0*�-��[z(
�_/j^ҸW�A�^�k��Z|�0�l���EZ�}�th5��t~����1���A�^��n%�3E�(re�+ꛓ+F������_/N�?�<�}�\@��f��&j������]���Y
                                                                                                                1   ���nS�����e̸
npm ERR! 
         �/�F�LVt���'�봆e1A\������=v�t�OO�y~$�A�a~ٱ�^�2�?�J�Y�f  y�(��w9O�/���   �������j�چ�8�ƫ��8\%�d�AYG��"��̹�
                                                                                                                                �ڰW^^~eR�
npm ERR!     at Object.parse (native)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:238:23)
npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:148:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:896:14)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:847:12)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-34-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/zeus/Glide/project/project-desktop
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! type unexpected_token
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/babelify/7.2.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/babelify/-/babelify-7.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-preset-es2015/6.5.0
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/css-loader/0.18.0
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-preset-es2015/-/babel-preset-es2015-6.5.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/1.8.3
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/require-dir/0.1.0
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/style-loader/0.13.0
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/require-dir/-/require-dir-0.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/transfer-webpack-plugin/0.1.4
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/transfer-webpack-plugin/-/transfer-webpack-plugin-0.1.4.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-addons-css-transition-group/-/react-addons-css-transition-group-0.14.7.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/radium/-/radium-0.16.6.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react/-/react-0.14.7.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-addons-update/-/react-addons-update-0.14.7.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-addons-pure-render-mixin/-/react-addons-pure-render-mixin-0.14.7.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/webpack/1.12.13
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/webpack/-/webpack-1.12.13.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-dom/-/react-dom-0.14.6.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-progress-bar-plus/-/react-progress-bar-plus-0.2.3.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/material-ui/-/material-ui-0.14.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-scroll/-/react-scroll-1.0.3.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-router/-/react-router-2.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-tap-event-plugin/-/react-tap-event-plugin-0.2.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-lazyload/-/react-lazyload-1.3.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-core/-/babel-core-6.5.1.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-loader/-/babel-loader-6.2.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/babelify/-/babelify-7.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-preset-es2015/-/babel-preset-es2015-6.5.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/require-dir/-/require-dir-0.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/transfer-webpack-plugin/-/transfer-webpack-plugin-0.1.4.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/webpack/-/webpack-1.12.13.tgz
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/zeus/Glide/project/project-desktop/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

My package.json is as under:

```
{
  "name": "Project_Server",
  "version": "0.13.2",
  "description": "Project Desktop client",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/callemall/material-ui.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack-dev-server.config.js --progress --inline --colors",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack-production.config.js --progress --colors"
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
    "babelify": "7.2.0",
    "css-loader": "0.18.0",
    "require-dir": "0.1.0",
    "style-loader": "0.13.0",
    "transfer-webpack-plugin": "0.1.4",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "webpack": "1.12.13"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "material-ui": "0.14.0",
    "radium": "0.16.6",
    "react": "0.14.7",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "0.14.7",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "0.14.7",
    "react-addons-update": "0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "0.14.6",
    "react-lazyload": "1.3.2",
    "react-progress-bar-plus": "0.2.3",
    "react-router": "2.0.0",
    "react-scroll": "1.0.3",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "0.2.2"
  }
}
```

npm-debug.log is below (No errors above this in debug-log)

```
441 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-loader/-/babel-loader-6.2.2.tgz
442 http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-preset-react/6.5.0
443 verbose bad json �\00\00\00\00\00�Tێ�0����������o�jU�����`�/�M7�j��cY�Jڪ!0�3sf�x��� e)4D������.�    �r%�8�k�%���`}�A�4+�����}���nڒKK�ZW)���\� e�q&g�{�O��
f�����/�'͔^��J  Ь�<+�����=��R��nx�������m@+˝2�O�:��J�kj��2�A[զ>���t`.�$��f�s���m����
�2��-f�A~Ɍ���ϭ�Bl';��Q����%����T��mg���s��"��X��sފ���'Lrnu�:r��
6����֐��U����ض��p�z�����Ag����V̶�r�Man�4_m��"
443 verbose bad json �$�l�0*�-��[z(�gx
�_/j^ҸW�A�^�k��Z|�0�l���EZ�}�th5��t~����1���A�^��n%�3E�(re�+ꛓ+F������_/N�?�<�}�\@��f��&j������]���Y1    ���nS�����e̸
443 verbose bad json �/�F�LVt���'�봆e1A\������=v�t��OO�y~$�A�a~ٱ�^�2�?�J�Y�f     y�(��w9O�/���   �������j�چ�8�ƫ��8\%�d�AYG��"��̹��ڰW^^~eR�\00\00
444 error registry error parsing json
445 silly registry.get cb [ 200,
445 silly registry.get   { server: 'CouchDB/1.5.0 (Erlang OTP/R16B03)',
445 silly registry.get     etag: '"2OLAOBPSX664F6WT145OT3DOD"',
445 silly registry.get     'content-type': 'application/json',
445 silly registry.get     'content-encoding': 'gzip',
445 silly registry.get     'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
445 silly registry.get     'content-length': '676',
445 silly registry.get     'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
445 silly registry.get     date: 'Tue, 05 Apr 2016 10:03:41 GMT',
445 silly registry.get     via: '1.1 varnish',
445 silly registry.get     age: '0',
445 silly registry.get     connection: 'keep-alive',
445 silly registry.get     'x-served-by': 'cache-ams4122-AMS',
445 silly registry.get     'x-cache': 'HIT',
445 silly registry.get     'x-cache-hits': '1',
445 silly registry.get     'x-timer': 'S1459850621.389755,VS0,VE99',
445 silly registry.get     vary: 'Accept' } ]
446 silly lockFile 51c7cdfc-babel-preset-react-6-5-0 babel-preset-react@6.5.0
447 silly lockFile 51c7cdfc-babel-preset-react-6-5-0 babel-preset-react@6.5.0
448 error SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
448 error �\00\00\00\00\00�Tێ�0����������o�jU�����`�/�M7�j��cY�Jڪ!0�3sf�x��� e)4D������.�   �r%�8�k�%���`}�A�4+�����}���nڒKK�ZW)���\� e�q&g�{�O��
f�����/�'͔^��J  Ь�<+�����=��R��nx�������m@+˝2�O�:��J�kj��2�A[զ>���t`.�$��f�s���m����
�2��-f�A~Ɍ���ϭ�Bl';��Q����%����T��mg���s��"��X��sފ���'Lrnu�:r��
6����֐��U����ض��p�z�����Ag����V̶�r�Man�4_m��"
448 error �$�l�0*�-��[z(�gx
�_/j^ҸW�A�^�k��Z|�0�l���EZ�}�th5��t~����1���A�^��n%�3E�(re�+ꛓ+F������_/N�?�<�}�\@��f��&j������]���Y1    ���nS�����e̸
448 error �/�F�LVt���'�봆e1A\������=v�t��OO�y~$�A�a~ٱ�^�2�?�J�Y�f    y�(��w9O�/���   �������j�چ�8�ƫ��8\%�d�AYG��"��̹��ڰW^^~eR�\00\00
448 error     at Object.parse (native)
448 error     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:238:23)
448 error     at Request.self.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:148:22)
448 error     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
448 error     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:896:14)
448 error     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
448 error     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:847:12)
448 error     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
448 error     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
448 error     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
449 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
449 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
449 error or email it to:
449 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
450 error System Linux 4.2.0-34-generic
451 error command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
452 error cwd /home/zeus/Glide/project/project-desktop
453 error node -v v0.10.25
454 error npm -v 1.3.10
455 error type unexpected_token
456 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: What is in `/home/zeus/Glide/project/project-desktop/npm-debug.log` ??

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using such an old version of Node/NPM? Or is that just what apt-get gave to you by default? They're both seriously out of date (whether that's what's causing the issue, I don't know, but it's worth checking).

Comment: I'm with @JoeClay. I think I had a very similar issue with Babel on an older node/npm just recently.

Comment: both of these versions were working fine few days ago, I need to update my module for that purpose I was doing some testings, I deleted my node_modules and did npm install and this is what I get

Comment: I would seriously advise to update Node.js and npm to at least their respective LTS versions (4.x and 2.x, respectively). It may be that a particular package is relying on features not available in npm 1.3.

Comment: You might want to try 'npm cache clean'.

Answer (score 1):

We have same problem, npm 1.3.10 and node 0.10.25. Can't currently upgrade the npm globally.

Our current workaround is to install newer npm via the old one locally, ie.

```
npm install npm@2.10.0
```

And then use it to install other dependencies

```
nodejs node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli install
```

Comment: As for the cause, apparently npm folks were testing gzip compression which isn't supported in 1.3.10 ([see github's issue comment](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12196#issuecomment-205855393))

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that people at NPM were testing gzip compression for package metadata, because the savings in bandwidth would make installs faster and more reliable for everyone. Unfortunately, npm@1.3 and older can't handle gzipped responses. Doubly unfortunately, the npm CLI team doesn't support npm@1.3 anymore, as it's quite old (and buggy).

[You can read about this issue from npm team here!](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12196#issuecomment-205855393)

So there was no issue with cache cleaning or older updates. Although I did update my `npm` to `3.8.5 Latest` and `node` to `v4.4.2 LTS` before knowing this problem and that resolved the issue.